# Do offsets in assembly represent addresses or bits?

Tags: assembly, x86, memory-address, addressing-mode

I am a bit confused, will inc [esi + 8] (lets say [esi] points to 0x0000001F in 8-bit memory) increment 0x00000027 or will it affect 0x00000020? I have seen a video implying it will affect the latter whereas regular pointers in ram go by addresses, not bits.

Edit: so sorry for this incredibly stupid question please restore my right to post

Comment: The video you saw is wrong, or you misinterpreted it.  (e.g. possibly it was talking about a microcontroller like 8051 where part of the address space is a bit-addressable view of regular physical memory (https://what-when-how.com/8051-microcontroller/bit-addresses-for-io-and-ram), but that wouldn't have a register called ESI.)

Comment: X86 is a byte machine, so each address represents one byte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Addresses are bytes. This will increment `0x00000027`.

This doesn't assemble because you're missing the size though. `inc {byte|word|dword|qword} ptr [esi + 8]` is what you want. (Operand size is required)